# Magento how to create partial invoice programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, invoice

With the ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799498/magento-create-partial-invoice-programmatically
I have tried but it's occurred only for shipping cost or single sku of multiple sku. I want to create $100 invoice out of $500 subtotal of order. I mean if subtotal is $500 I want to create two separate invoice. one is $100 & another is $400 . 
Need a help, Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Any Solutions about that?

Comment: Not yet get any solution.

Comment: Did you managed to get this done ? I've same requirement.